# ajax call in each loop functions as not expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a function to output an array named `DisplayComments(comments)`. Within this function, I make an ajax call to retrieve the `replies` associated with `comments`.

When ajax is run to retrieve the `replies`, after the array is returned from web api controller, the code jumps out of the ajax and just go to the last line of the `each loop`, which is `$('#div_ListOfComments').append(replies);`. Then it goes back to the first line of the loop, which is `var cid = comment.CommentId;` and continue with the next comment item. Then, ajax call happens for the second `comment`, and it behaves the same way. It never visits the `Success` status of ajax call until `each loop` is completed for all `comments`. Then, it moves to Success section and runs the code once for each `reply` item to display them on the form.

However, I need to attach the `replies` just under each comment, in other words, I need to append the `replies` to `$('#div_ListOfComments')` just after `comment` is appended. However, the code illustrated below does not function in the expected way. It appends all comments. Then it appends the replies. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code below ?

```
    function LoadCommentsForPost(postid) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Comment/GetCommentsByPost?pid=' + postid,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {                 

            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                var comments = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                comments = comments["$values"];
                DisplayComments(comments);
            }
        });
    }

    function DisplayComments(comments) {

        $('#div_ListOfComments').html('');
        $.each(comments, function (index, comment) {
            //the current comment is appended to $('#div_ListOfComments')

            var cid = comment.CommentId;
            var replies;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Reply/GetRepliesByComment?cid=' + cid,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    //VS break-point works just before here
                    //and I see a valid return value from VS
                    //the program continue to work outside of the ajax
                    //with this line below: $('#div_ListOfComments').append.....
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            });

            $('#div_ListOfComments').append(replies);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[John is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178365/4690611).
Also, I'll suggest you change the use of cascated ajax calls. You can use the deferred/promise  approach.

Your code will look like this

```js
function LoadCommentsForPost(){
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Comment/GetCommentsByPost?pid=' + postid,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
function LoadCommentsForPostError(x, y, z) {
    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
}
function RetrievedComments(jqXHR, textStatus)
{
    var comments = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    comments = comments["$values"];
    DisplayComments(comments);
}
function DisplayComments(comments) {
    $('#div_ListOfComments').html('');
    $.each(comments, function (index, comment) {
        var cid = comment.CommentId;

        // Append the comment to $('#div_ListOfComments').
        // Append an empty div to $('#div_ListOfComments') that will hold the replies,
        // giving it an id based on cid.

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Reply/GetRepliesByComment?cid=' + cid,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
            // Put the replies in the div with the id based on cid.
            // cid will have the correct value because this is a closure.
            }
        });
    });
}

$.when(LoadCommentsForPost()).then(RetrievedComments, LoadCommentsForPostError);
```

More at [$.when documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous. The call to `$.ajax()` just initiates the ajax call. Then the line of of code after it is executed. The `success` callback is not called until after the server returns the response to the ajax call.

You also cannot count on the ajax responses coming back in the same order you made the requests.

You could do something like this:

```
function DisplayComments(comments) {
    $('#div_ListOfComments').html('');
    $.each(comments, function (index, comment) {
        var cid = comment.CommentId;

        // Append the comment to $('#div_ListOfComments').
        // Append an empty div to $('#div_ListOfComments') that will hold the replies,
        // giving it an id based on cid.

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Reply/GetRepliesByComment?cid=' + cid,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                // Put the replies in the div with the id based on cid.
                // cid will have the correct value because this is a closure.
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Another way to do this would be to hold the comments and replies in data until the last ajax call returns, and then add them all to the page.

```
function DisplayComments(comments) {
    var replies = {};
    var deferreds = $.map(comments, function(comment) {
        var cid = comment.CommentId;
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Reply/GetRepliesByComment?cid=' + cid,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(reply) {
                replies[cid] = reply;
            }
        });
    });

    // This executes the function when all the ajax calls have returned.
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
        $('#div_ListOfComments').html('');
        $.each(comments, function(i, comment) {
            var reply = replies[comment.id];
            $('#div_ListOfComments').append(comment.text).append(reply);
        });
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLx4s7t0/)

Comment: My answer answers your question as to why your code was not working and suggests two ways to fix it. Leonardo's answer is not a third alternative but instead is a different way of implementing my first suggestion.